# Word is not opening from Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Word is not opening from powerbuilder in windows 10 machine.But it works fine in windows 7 machine.If the word is already opened and try from the application,it's working fine.Otherwise hanging the application and crashes.

Comment: Versions or PowerBuilder? Word?

Comment: Powerbuilder version is 12.5 and Microsoft word for office 365 pro plus.

Comment: I'm throwing you a hail-mary here. Seems we had something like this and it was something about how Windows uses command line arguments and/or the 'file path' if you're referring to physical drive path or other UNC, I recall Windows 10 requiring me having the "slashes" doubled up for some reason or nothing worked. Can't remember more.

Comment: could you try running a cmd for word? if that work properly, then you can call that cmd.

Comment: Could you show the command/script you use to open Word?

Comment: ole_object.ConnectToNewObject("word.application")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve it adding office intallation root (probably C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15) to Path environment variables.

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings (on the left panel) -> Environment variables -> Edit "Path" variable.

Later you only need to call to winword.exe